# How to disable comments on Page on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a create a page

**http://www.example.com/sitemap**

there is some static content on that page.  and under template **homepagete_hierachy**  is coming.

But i am getting comments on that page. How to disable comments on that page 
here is my page template

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>


<div id="content">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>           

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>          


</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Edit Page, then at the top right corner there's "Screen options", click there and make sure "Discussion" and "Comments" are selected. Then you will see below the page textarea the checkboxes to allow or disallow comments and trackbacks for that page.